# Hilbert polynomial of a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hilbert-polynomial

Why a point $p$ in $P^n$ has Hilbert polynomial 1?
I know that the Hilbert polynomial has degree $0$ (=the dimension of $p$) so it's a constant polynomial, but why it's the constant 1?

Comment: This is one of those Hilbert polynomials you can compute straight from the definition without much trouble. Have you tried that?

Comment: I know that the Hilbert Polynomial of $p$, $P_p(l)=dim_k(S/I(p))_l$ for $l\gg0$, I have to show that this dimension is 1... I don't know how to prove it

Comment: Really? Start by writing down what $S$ is, and what the ideal of a nice point is.

Comment: $(S/I(p))_l=S_l/(I(p)\cap S_l)$. If $p=(0:\dots:a_i:\dots:0)$  and $F$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $l$ in $I(p)$, then $F(p)=0$; $F=\sum\limits_{d=(d_o,\dots,d_n) : d_0+\dots+d_n=l} C_dx_o^{d_1}\dots x_n^{d_n}$. Let $d'=(0,\dots,l,\dots,0)$, using $F(p)=0$ follows that $C_{d'}=0$. So $dim_k S_l\cap I(p)=\binom{l+n}{n}-1$: all monomials of degree l but not $x_i^l$. so $dim_k(S/I(p))_l=dim_k S_l-dim_k S_l\cap I(p)$=1. is this corrct? (thanks for your help!)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You may wish to record that as an answer to your own question.